# Deploy smart contract to Ether scan network

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am trying to make a sample smart contract and migrate to ether scan explorer but not able to deploy. I am using truffle, infura and metamask to test my application. i am able to compile it successfully but when i try to run migrate it says `everything is upto date, nothing to compile`. My truffle.js file looks like this

```
    ropsten: {
      provider: function (){
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 
        'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/api_key')
      },
      network_id: 3,
      from: 'address',
      gasPrice: 25000000000000
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete all your artifacts (bin and abi files) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

In Truffle it is necessary to specify the network if using other than `develop`. Also, make sure your account has enough funds on the ropsten network to deploy the contracts!